# Reading a parameter from web.xml in another package to init a view

Tags: java, facescontext

To get a init parameter from same package, I can make it:

in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>PARAM</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and my java class:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter( "PARAM" );
```

It's ok for same package. But, if I want access via my class java, a web.xml from another package? How I should make it?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have a single web.xml per war. You could set parameters in a file in the same class package, and read it like this:

```
YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/Parameters.xml");
```